# Column Chart with condition-based coloring in R and highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts

I want to produce a column chart with highcharts in R which would display the values larger than 0 in blue color and values less than 0 in red. Is there any straightforward way of doing this?

My chart code is simple as this:

```
hchart(
  df_temps, 
  "column",
  hcaes(x = Device, y = Temperature))
```

The data (df_temps) looks like this:

```
Device    Temperature
A         -0.78
B         14.8
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, this would work:

```
df_temps <- data.frame(Device = c("A","B"), Temperature = c(-0.78,14.8))
hchart(
  df_temps, 
  "column",
  hcaes(x = Device, y = Temperature, color=c("#910000","#2f7ed8")))
```

More generally and "condition-based":

```
df_temps <- data.frame(Device = c("A","B"), Temperature = c(-0.78,14.8))
df_temps$col <- ifelse(sign(df_temps$Temperature)==-1, "#910000","#2f7ed8")
    hchart(
      df_temps, 
      "column",
      hcaes(x = Device, y = Temperature, color=col))
```

Comment: Maybe you like this shade of red `#c42525` more.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, this works great. Could you please also advise on how could I display in the tooltip something like Temperature: -0.78? By default is says Series 1: -0.78.

Comment: Here you go:
`hc <- hchart(df_temps, "column",hcaes(x = Device, y = Temperature, color=col))
  hc_tooltip(hc,pointFormat = "Temperature: {point.y}")`
Hope that helps.